# is there a way to display author image in joomla article

Tags: joomla

I'm currently designing a website for a client and the client is requesting to display the author picture and name on every article. I searched but, can't find an option to do that.

Is there a way to display the author picture on each article?

Comment: Author picture from which extension?

Comment: yes but by "author picture", I assume you are talking about avatars like we have on Stackoverflow and Joomla doesn't have this feature, therefore they must be coming from another extension such as Community Builder

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of extensions that will let you integrate with Gravatar and other services.

In terms of the Joomla core, you can already link an author to a contact page with an image (when the author is the linked user) and you could write a plugin to pull the image from the contact record since you already have the record id.  You could also store the image location as part of the user profile and write a plugin for that.